# Win 7:Turn Of Preview Pane for .txt

Tags: windows-7

I constantly get error when i select a .txt file  in explorer that hangs it for some 40 seconds
then allow to view the content.
How i can turn that PreviewPane off?

Comment: Do you want to completely turn the Preview Pane off for all extensions, or only for .txt files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open explorer and select the 'Organise' tab (top left). Select Layout then deselect Preview pane. However, that will disable all previews.

I believe changing the default file handler for .txt files will also disable previews.